# SQL with left join and group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I've 2 tables, one with all my journal lines (table name: BoekstukRegels) and one with all journal descriptions (table name: balansen).

This works fine:

```
SELECT SUM(BoekRegelBedrag) AS TOTAL, BoekRegelGrootboekNr, BoekRegelPeriode
FROM BoekstukRegels
WHERE BoekregelUserId = 45 AND BoekRegelPeriode LIKE '2012%'
GROUP BY BoekRegelGrootboekNr
```

But the problem is I dont get the description. So I tried this:

```
 SELECT SUM(BoekRegelBedrag) as total, BoekRegelPeriode, BoekRegelGrootboekNr, BaOmschrijving, BaSoort
 FROM BoekstukRegels
 LEFT JOIN balansen ON BoekRegelGrootboekNr = BaGbNumber
 WHERE BoekregelUserId = 45 AND BoekRegelPeriode LIKE '2012%' AND BaSoort = 2
 GROUP BY BoekRegelGrootboekNr
```

This gets me the description so that worked fine but the problem is that the totals dont match. I know what the problem is and that is because there are duplicates in the table balansen.

So in one way or another the table balansen needs a group by also but i cant get it working so i hope someone else can help me further.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how to do the necessary group by on the other table to get the results you want?  If so, then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(BoekRegelBedrag) as total, 
       BoekRegelPeriode, 
       BoekRegelGrootboekNr, 
       BaOmschrijving, 
       BaSoort

FROM   BoekstukRegels LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT field1, field2, etc. 
        FROM   balansen 
        GROUP BY FieldToGroupOn) tbl

       ON BoekRegelGrootboekNr = BaGbNumber

WHERE    BoekregelUserId = 45 AND BoekRegelPeriode LIKE '2012%' AND BaSoort = 2
GROUP BY BoekRegelGrootboekNr
```

Comment: I'm not able to add a comment to jerjer's answer, but I think he's addressing a problem that exists in MS SQL that you don't have when it comes to referencing non-aggregated fields in the select list because MySql allows this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include non aggregate fields on the group by clause:
Try this:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(BoekRegelBedrag) as total, 
   BoekRegelPeriode, 
   BoekRegelGrootboekNr, 
   BaOmschrijving, 
   BaSoort
FROM BoekstukRegels
   LEFT JOIN balansen 
      ON BoekRegelGrootboekNr = BaGbNumber
WHERE
   BoekregelUserId = 45 AND 
   BoekRegelPeriode LIKE '2012%' 
   AND BaSoort = 2
GROUP BY 
   BoekRegelPeriode, 
   BoekRegelGrootboekNr, 
   BaOmschrijving, 
   BaSoort
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are duplicates in balansen, you will need to decide which records are important to you, then you will be able to do something like

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT BaGbNumber, MAX(BaOmschrijving) AS BaOmschrijving
    FROM balansen WHERE AND BaSoort = 2 GROUP BY BaGbNumber
) AS grouped_balansen ON BoekRegelGrootboekNr = BaGbNumber
```

Now you will join to one row per input row and get your totals correct.